# Process.Start() on Xamarin Forms Null Reference

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, null

I'm trying to create a button on the screen every time the text received via DB is a link. Thus, the button when pressed would redirect the user to the corresponding web page. However, even though the text is not null, I get the following error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' I'm using Xamarin Forms on .NET 6 and Visual Studio Community 2022. I don't know if it's something simple, because I've never really tried to do something like that.

````
private Button GetButtonLinkSolution(SolutionDTO solution)
        {
            Button btnLink = new Button();
            btnLink.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["btnNiveis"];
            btnLink.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#2b2b80");
            btnLink.Text = "Answer (click here)";
            string textBotao = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < solution.Text.Length; i++)
            {
                textBotao = textBotao + String.Concat(solution.Text[i]);
            }
            btnLink.Clicked += (sender, args) => ButtonLink_Clicked(sender, args, textBotao);
            return btnLink;
        }

        private void ButtonLink_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args, string textBotao)
        {
           Process.Start(textBotao);
        }```
````

Comment: Use [Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/launcher?tabs=ios) to open links, not Process.Start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a lot of things that I don't understand in your code and are confusing to me, like for instance your separate event is called from the button event to assign your string.

For instance:

```
 string textBotao = "";
 for (int i = 0; i < solution.Text.Length; i++)
 {
   textBotao = textBotao + String.Concat(solution.Text[i]);
 }
```

This piece of code will loop in all the items in your Text array into a single string and then assign it to `textBotao` which I am not even sure would be a valid URL at the end in any case I am guessing that what you are trying to do is open a URL.

Now if you have Xamarin Essentials(Probably do):

Then you should use the following Essentials API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/open-browser?tabs=android

For Android 11 plus make sure you have this query in your Manifest:

```
  <queries>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="http"/>
  </intent>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="https"/>
  </intent>
  </queries>
```

And then open browser like so :

```
var textBotaoUri = new System.Uri(textBotao);
await OpenBrowser(textBotaoUri);
```

Where OpenBrowser is something like below :

```
    public async Task OpenBrowser(Uri uri)
    {
        try
        {
            await Browser.OpenAsync(uri, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // An unexpected error occured. No browser may be installed on the device.
        }
    }
```

There are also some customization options that can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/open-browser?tabs=android#customization